# How can an ethernet cable from a POE doorbell be embedded in the side frame of the door?

Tags: door-frame, doorbell, cables, poe

I have a POE doorbell with a CAT6 cable coming from the attic. How can I create a vertical straight channel on the side of the door to embed the cable?

I have a trim router, but it is too deep to center the channel and free-handing the cut would look terrible. I have a circular saw and a cutoff tool, but neither blade is wide enough and making a straight vertical cut that long will be difficult. I have a Dremel, but also a nearly impossible cut.

[image: doorbell poe cable]

Comment: Usually would use a guide for saw to make two long straight lines and then chisel it out

Comment: Given that you're gonna need to do some repair work anyway, why not just rout the *front* face of the wood?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a vibrating tool to cut a valley from the hole up to wherever the cable needs to go. ( you did not provide a pic so we are guessing on that)  The cut does not have to be perfectly straight because you are going to replace the wood that comes out.

Save the wedge that comes out. You will be putting it back.

Trim off enough from the bottom (inner) edge of the wedge to fit the cable.

Push the cable in the valley.  Glue the wedge back in. Touch up the paint.

[image]

Pic with diagram to understand what I am talking about.

the yellow is the wedge cut out, Red is the outside face. Cut off where the black line is.

Comment: Great idea, thanks.